# initialising view model at runtime

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, runtime

I'm working with silverlight 4 and I use MVVM design. I have created a business silverlight application and I want to change view model informations while authentifying I mean when a user is authentified the model view bring this user's informations from a database. I tried to do that using events but I couldn't can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can just call wcf methods in viewmodel. in completed handler init your necessary fields

Answer (score 0):

[MVVMLight](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) has a Messenger class, try that.